# Linking to a .dll file without the .lib

Tags: c, dll, name-mangling

I need to rewrite some Delphi code to C++ and we need to link to the dynamic library `TMLComm2004.dll`. It turns out that we don't have any `.lib` file so we decided to generate it, using the following command lines:

```
dumpbin /EXPORTS C:\Users\fayard\Desktop\TMLComm2004.dll > C:\Users\fayard\Desktop\TMLComm2004.txt
```

We obtain the following file

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.00.24215.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file C:\Users\fayard\Desktop\TMLComm2004.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for TMLcomm.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    401F6AD5 time date stamp Tue Feb  3 10:33:09 2004
        0.00 version
          1 ordinal base
          27 number of functions
          27 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00001122 _MSK_COFFDownloadFlash@16
          2    1 0000114F _MSK_COFFDownloadRAM@20
          3    2 0000106E _MSK_CheckSum@12
          4    3 00001172 _MSK_CloseComm@0
          5    4 00001190 _MSK_GetActiveBoard@4
          6    5 0000109B _MSK_GetBoardInfo@8
          7    6 0000104B _MSK_GetBytesCountInQueue@0
          8    7 0000119A _MSK_GetChar@4
          9    8 000010E6 _MSK_GetCharNoWait@4
         10    9 000011A4 _MSK_GetCommBaudRate@4
         11    A 000010DC _MSK_GetHostBoard@4
         12    B 0000108C _MSK_OpenComm@16
         13    C 000011DB _MSK_ReceiveData@16
         14    D 000011CC _MSK_ReceiveMessage@4
         15    E 0000105A _MSK_RegisterReceiveUnsolicitedMsgHandler@4
         16    F 000011AE _MSK_ResetMSKBoard@0
         17   10 00001037 _MSK_SendChar@4
         18   11 000010EB _MSK_SendData@16
         19   12 0000126C _MSK_SendMessage@4
         20   13 0000128F _MSK_SetActiveBoard@4
         21   14 00001136 _MSK_SetB0BlockAsData@4
         22   15 0000100A _MSK_SetBoardBaudRate@4
         23   16 00001019 _MSK_SetCharMode@4
         24   17 00001168 _MSK_SetCommBaudRate@4
         25   18 00001050 _MSK_SetDebugWindow@8
         26   19 00001276 _MSK_SetHostBoard@4
         27   1A 00001046 _MSK_UpdateCommTimeouts@0

  Summary

        C000 .data
        3000 .idata
        6000 .rdata
        4000 .reloc
       21000 .rsrc
       3E000 .text
        2000 shdata
```

Then, we have edited the `TMLComm2014.txt` file and changed it to a `.def` file with the @xx removed. The file looks like:

```
EXPORTS
_MSK_COFFDownloadFlash
...
```

Then, we generate a `.lib` file with:

```
lib /def:C:\Users\fayard\Desktop\TMLComm2004.def /out:C:\Users\fayard\Desktop\TMLComm2004.lib
```

We compile the following program:

```
extern "C" {
  bool MSK_OpenComm(unsigned char a, unsigned short b, bool c, unsigned char d);
}

...
```

When we compile and link against the `.lib`, we get an error:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _MSK_OpenComm referenced in function...
```

What's wrong with what I do?

**Update**

I have managed to compile with:

```
extern "C" {
  bool __stdcall MSK_OpenComm(unsigned char a, unsigned short b, bool c, unsigned char d);
}
```

but now the problem is at link time. I am puzzled as from command line, I have:

```
==================================================
dumpbin /headers TMLComm.lib

  Version      : 0
  Machine      : 14C (x86)
  TimeDateStamp: 5964C365 Tue Jul 11 14:24:05 2017
  SizeOfData   : 00000022
  DLL name     : TMLComm2004.dll
  Symbol name  : __MSK_OpenComm@16
  Type         : code
  Name type    : no prefix
  Hint         : 11
  Name         : _MSK_OpenComm@16

==================================================
dumpbin /exports TMLComm.dll

         12    B 0000108C _MSK_OpenComm@16

==================================================
```

Compilation goes fine now, but the problem is at link time:

```
link tmlcomm.obj Motor.obj main.obj TMLComm.lib /out:main.exe


Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24215.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

tmlcomm.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MSK_OpenComm@16 referenced in function "bool __cdecl msk_opencomm(unsigned char,unsigned short,bool,unsigned char)" (?msk_opencomm@@YA_NEG_NE@Z)
Teclis.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: IMPLIB should import these functions from the DLL. But this looks like a VC++ (or compatible) DLL. That means you'll have to handle the decorations: [See here](http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol4/0012/Using_Visual_C_DLLs_with_CBuilder.htm).

Comment: "Unresolved external symbol ..." You left out the interesting part: which symbols are reported as undefined? Could linking to MSVCRT.dll help?

Comment: @Rudy: _MSK_OpenComm is reported as undefined

Comment: Probably because it is exported as `_MSK_OpenComm@16`, not as `_MSK_OpenComm`. `.def` files are only considered when the C++ code is compiled and linked, not when it is imported.

Comment: @Rudy: That might be the reason. But I have no idea how to call a function with an @ in its name. It is forbidden by C/C++.

Comment: Take a look at the link I posted in my comment.

Comment: You could always dynamically import the functions, using `LoadLibrary`and `GetProcAddress`, i.e. without an import lib.

Comment: @Rudy. I have managed to generate a `.def` file that translates the mangled names to the C names. Now it compiles, but when I run the program I get: The procedure entry point MSK_SetBoardBaudRate could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\...\Main.exe . Why is he looking the .exe as a dynamic library?

Comment: hard to tell from here, sorry. But it seems to be looking for `MSK_SetBoardBaudRate`, while the DLL exports `_MSK_SetBoardBaudRate@4`. That it reports the wrong executable is not so important, fact is that you still have the same problem (but now at runtime): it can't find the proper exported names. Try dynamic linking instead. There, you can give the proper name as a string and assign it to any suitable function pointer. No problems with decoration anymore.

Comment: FWIW, how did the Delphi code link to the DLL?

Comment: @Rudy: It was declared that way: `function MSK_OpenComm;                  external k_TMLCommName name '_MSK_OpenComm@16';`

Comment: In Delphi, it is quite simple, indeed. In C++Builder, that is not so simple. Does your .def file have entries like `MSK_SetBoardBaudRate=_MSK_SetBoardBaudRate@4` ? That should actually work.

Comment: @Rudy: I have tried that but it did not work. But using `__stdcall` in the C files seems to look for the right function. Now it complains about not finding it (check the updated original question).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Microsoft's [documentation of decorated names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56h2zst2.aspx#FormatC). For C, a leading underscore and a trailing `@<number>` denotes the `stdcall` calling convention, which is different from the standard `cdecl`.

So, you should just modify your declarations for all functions where the symbol ends with `@<number>`:

```
extern "C" {
  __stdcall bool MSK_OpenComm(unsigned char a, unsigned short b, bool c, unsigned char d);
}
```

<strike>I'm not sure whether stripping the `@<number>` part from the `.def` file is the right thing to do, I doubt it, but just try it out.</strike>

From my experiment with `MinGW`s tool for creating a `.def` file (`gendef`), the name in the `.def` should **not** include the leading underscore, but it **should** include the `@<number>` part at the end. So for this example function, the `.def` should have the following line:

```
MSK_OpenComm@16
```

An alternative to manually creating these required files are the tools that come with `MinGW`. You could just do the following:

```
gendef foobar.dll                     # generates the .def
dlltool -d foobar.def -l foobar.lib   # generates the import library
```

Based on your comments, you **might** need to manually edit the `.def` file `gendef` is giving you to contain lines like this:

```
MSK_OpenComm@16=_MSK_OpenComm@16
```

It seems that `gendef` could be confused because the dll exports *decorated names* which isn't expected.

---

When using an *import library*, this will have "static stubs" named like the actual exported symbols of the DLL, but with `__imp__` prepended. To account for this, you need yet another attribute in your declarations:

```
extern "C" {
  __declspec(dllimport) __stdcall bool MSK_OpenComm(unsigned char a, unsigned short b, bool c, unsigned char d);
}
```

Comment: That's cool if you are **writing** the DLL, but not if you are merely consuming an existing DLL written in VC++ from a different compiler. The DLL could have been written with a .def file giving nice and clean undecorated names, but it wasn't. This won't do much for the C++Builder code consuming the DLL.

Comment: Of course it will. The `__stdcall` in the **declaration** you use will tell the compiler for what kind of symbol to look and how to call it. -- but I overlooked something different I guess ... (and edited)

Comment: @RudyVelthuis if this is true, the compiler is unusable for the windows platform. I could imagine the actual attributes might look different from what I have in my answer (which works for MSVC as well as gcc and clang on windows) -- but there **has** to be a way to declare functions as `stdcall` and use them, even when the DLL was compiled with a different compiler. The win32 ABI mandates that.

Comment: @Felix: Thanks for your help. I have tried to follow your path but I am stuck at a later position. The description is in the updated original question.

Comment: @Felix: no it isn't. The Win32 ABI has undecorated names, even when they are __stdcall. Many 3rd parties also generate undecorated names using a .def file (and that will work in VC++ as well as in C++Builder). Only those that generate names with underscore and at-num pose some problems (or at least more work) for C++Builder users.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I don't see where the question relates to C++Builder, but anyways, although you can do any symbol naming with .def files and import libraries, it's just not useful if your tools don't support what's standard on the platform.

Comment: @Felix: I have removed the underscore. Now the link goes fine, but the program does not run. It says: "The procedure entry point MSK_OpenComm@16 could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\...\Main.exe"

Comment: @Felix: I am confused too by this message

Comment: @Felix: I have tried with __declspec too. Same problem.

Comment: @Felix: This was a type. I was linking the `.lib`. The problem is now when I run the program. As said above, it seems to believe that `Main.exe` is a dynamic library which is strange.

Comment: @Felix: It does not work. I have tried to generate the .def and .lib from Minw 32 bit (I am using a 32-bit library), and with __declspec(dllimport) it just says that it can't find the `__imp__...` symbol when linking.

Comment: @InsideLoop check `nm TMLComm.lib`, it should show a symbol `00000000 I __imp__MSK_OpenComm@16`. Did you use the command lines for `gendef` and `dlltool` I showed in my answer?

Comment: @Felix: Yes, I have used the commands you have used. When running `nm TMLComm2004.lib`, I get `00000000 I __imp___MSK_OpenComm@16@16`, with 3 `_` after the imp and 2 `@16`. Just so you know, the program is then linked with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @Felix: No, the `.def` contains `_MSK_OpenComm@16@16`

Comment: @InsideLoop added another edit, my answer is now ultimatively patchwork -- you seem to have an unusual situation here ;)

Comment: @Felix: I have tried your suggestion, but no more luck

Comment: @InsideLoop did you check the resulting .lib with `nm`? It **must** have a symbol `I __imp__MSK_OpenComm@16`. In the `.def`, the string after the equals sign is the symbol exported by the DLL. [See the documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx1zcd3.aspx), instead of the name, you could also use the "ordinal number".

Comment: @Felix: Yes, it does have this symbol.

Comment: @Felix: Aren't you puzzled about the fact that it seems to take my `Main.exe` as a dynamic library?

Comment: @InsideLoop not if you *don't* use `__declspec(dllimport)`. You *have* to use it, linking on windows works in two tiers...

Comment: @Felix: I use __declspec(dllimport) now. But it does not make a difference.

Comment: It's **impossible** this doesn't make a difference. You can't link a DLL without an import library, and the `__declspec(dllimport)` on the declaration of a function tells the linker what kind of symbol to look for (the one prefixed `__imp__`). If you can link successfully but get a problem at runtime, and you actually used `__declspec(dllimport)`, something was still wrong in the .def file the import library was generated from. See my earlier comment with a link to the documentation.